# The response is not returned from Azure Database for MySQL when I try to connect from command prompt and MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, azure, local

I run into the problem which I wrote as a Title.

The details are below.

### Environments and Settings

- using the Azure free plan.
- created Azure Database for MySQL server (version 8.0).
- Deny public network access: No
- added firewall rule Start IP: 0.0.0.0 - End IP: 255.255.255.255.
- Enforce SSL connection: DISABLED
- Client OS: Windows 10 Pro Version 2004 OS Build 19041.685

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy6To.png)
[Connection security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4zJw.png)

### Ehenomenon

- I can connect from Azure Cloud Shell.
- I can connect from local [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) client (Community Edition 21.2.3).
- However, I cannot connect from local Command Prompt or MySQL Workbench. The response is not returned.
  It seems to be hanged out. I allowed these apps to communicate via Windows Defender firewall.

[Azure Cloud Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U66aw.png)
[DBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msz2B.png)

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUWTi.png)
[MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOJ11.png)

[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6WoU.png)

What's wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with the latest MySQL 8.0.27 release. I've encountered the same issues you describe when trying to connect using the command line from different MacOS and Linux machines.

There 's also a bug reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105288
I suggest you add your findings to it as well.

I tried a bunch of different things before simply rolling back to 8.0.26, which still works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your help very much! I confirmed the symptoms, and I added comment to the mysql bug report.

Comment: Does anybody know if this was resolved with the MySQL 8.0.27 release? Sql workbench is still hanging and a site that tries to access MySql still hanging. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewGreatorex it was introduced with 8.0.27.